# Flask Update SQLite Record

Tags: python, sqlite, http, flask, patch

Using Flask, I'm trying to implement HTTP `PATCH`. I am using SQLite.

Here's what I have:

```
if 'name' in data.keys():
    db.execute('UPDATE places SET name=%s WHERE id=%s', (str(data['name']), str(data_id)))
```

This yields the following error: `OperationalError: near "%": syntax error`

What is wrong with my parametrisaton? I've looked up a few examples that pretty much look like this. I tried adding a % before the parameters parenthesis and that is also failing. I also tried concatenating using `+`'s but that also doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQLite, parameter placeholders are not `%s` but `?`.

Answer (score 0):

Need a quote like this `name='%s'` by SQL syntax